# Security Seting in Elasticsearch, xpack showing inconsistent behavior

Tags: elasticsearch, monitoring, elastic-stack

My ES cluster is running in production mode(on Kubernetes). It is accessible only within the organization so, for now, there is no need for securing the connection between ES nodes with certificates. While setting up the cluster I just added `xpack.security.enabled: true` that helped me in setting up a basic Kibana authentication, everything was working as expected until I restarted my data nodes pods and now it showing the following error:

```
ERROR: [1] bootstrap checks failed
[1]: Transport SSL must be enabled if security is enabled on a [basic] license. Please set [xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled] to [true] or disable security by setting [xpack.security.enabled] to [false]
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message is pretty explicit: You must have TLS certificates to use security. Which also makes sense from a security point of view, especially on Kubernetes where you don't have much protection out of the box otherwise.

If you don't want to set up certificates and other stuff on Kubernetes, have a look at the Kubernetes Operator, which does that for you: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/current/k8s-quickstart.html

Comment: Could you please suggest how to setup TLS certificates in Kubernetes? For my data and master nodes, I have separate  statefulsets but I am getting DNS specific issues.

Comment: What is "DNS specific issues"? I'd look into [`xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/security-settings.html#ssl-tls-settings) where you can define how strict you want the checks to be.

Comment: @Xerra, Thanks for your suggestion, I have tried out this property, but as per my knowledge this property `xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode` will disables the cert verification, right? I have applied this property in my kibana and elasticsearch pods but now I am getting  `X does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer(CN=Y)`.

Comment: So to which value did you set it? And in the end I assume your certificate just doesn't contain the hostname you are using, so ideally you should add it there.